# How does an 'if' statement checking happen in memory?

Tags: php, if-statement

Please read the code below:

```
<?php
    $flag = 1;
    $name = $_GET['name'];
    if($name == NULL){
       $flag = 0;
    }

 // some more code and checking....
 ?>
```

Here most of the time 'name' parameter will not be 'NULL' . If it is null, i am setting an error flag to 0. 
I was told that we have to use positive approach in programming. ie Since most of the time 'name' parameter is not going to be 'NULL' I should write the above code as:

```
if($name != NULL){
  $flag=1;
}else{
  $flag =0;
}
```

The above code improves performance because of the way the 'if' statement checking($name == NULL and $name != NULL) works.(this is what was told)

Does this kind of positive approach help improve performance?
How does an 'if' statement check for the 'if' condition in memory?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Worst case scenario, the difference would still be so insignificant it's not even worth considering.

Comment: @Sangam254:  I agree with Mannimarco.  On any modern processor, the difference will be a few nanoseconds, if any.  CPU branch prediction might absorb the time taken such that there is *no* timing difference.

Comment: Plus you're even confusing memory for, as wallyk says, CPU cycles. You are kind of overthinking all this — PHP is fast enough that you don't need to worry about these little nuggets of code.

Comment: [Branch predictor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor) might help you understand more

Comment: What exactly is "Positive Approach" ?

Comment: [Premature optimisation is the route of all evil](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does this kind of positive approach help improve performance?

Definitely **NO.**
No kind if such a microscopic approach will ever affect performance. At least not in the PHP world, where CPU has to perform hundreds of thousands such comparisons until it finally reach your single alone solitary condition.

Also, in case you have to set just a boolean flag, no need to write if condition at all - it is redundant (NOT in terms of performance but just in terms of code consistency and sanity), as every logical operator already returns a boolean:

```
$flag = ($name != NULL);
```

Anyway, a thing that really worth attention is that your code will issue an error in case $_GET['name'] not set.
So, in your case it seems the best approach would be just one line of code:

```
$flag = isset($_GET['name']);
```

Answer (score 2):

For such simple statements I wouldn't care about performance and use the one thats more readable / maintainable.

This simple allocations and comparisions are rather cheap. If you are hitting a database, etc the possible performance/memory difference is pointless here.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're writing code for facebook neither of these approaches is going to have a noticeable affect on the performance of your web application. (Perhaps even then it might not make a difference.)

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned about performance, use c or c++.

http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32/which-programming-languages-are-fastest.php

Notice that PHP is 45x slower than c or c++.

When using PHP, just try to make your code clear, clean and consistent so it'll be maintainable by you and others.

Hope that helps...